# How to seperate a nested array with non-jason objects of a data frame column, to different columns?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I am trying to split the attributes which contain arrays into individual attributes in my dataframe. The rows of the data frame column that I want to split have the following form:

```py
[
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0},
  {lockstatus=0, openstatus=0, enablestatus=0}
]
```

Is there a way to seperate these Attributes when they are defined with `=` instead of `:`.

**Note:** `json.normalize` function does not work for me because the objects are defined with `=` instead of `:`.

Comment: is it all in a string ?

Comment: I realized that the whole thing is in string. Its a sensor data Is it possible to change string into json after replacing '=' with ':' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing the '=' with ':' in the dataframe column, and normalize it.

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace('=',':')
```

Comment: I realized that the whole thing is in string. Its a sensor data Is it possible to change string into json after replacing '=' with ':' ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand where this data is coming from. It is neither a valid Python syntax nor a json one. Do you have a file containing this data as a string?

If you have such a file, you can convert "="'s to ":"'s by:

```py
with open("myfile.someextension") as file:
    file_str = file.read()

replace_equal_to_colon = file_str.replace("=", ":")

with open("write_changed_str_back.someextension", "w") as file:
    file.write(replace_equal_to_colon)
```

After that you have a valid syntax, and you can do whatever you want with it.